# CSS transform doesn't work on inline elements

Tags: css, css-transforms

I wanted to mirror letter `E` in the word `WEBLOG` so I used CSS transform property but it doesn't work if I wrap the text inside a span but it works if I assing `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;`

**So transforms doesn't apply to inline elements?**

[**Example 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hwMm/) (Fails To Transform)

```
<h1>W<span>E</span>BLOG</h1>

h1 span {
    transform:rotate(7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -moz-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Opera */
}
```

[**Example 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hwMm/1/) (Works, If Used `display: block` OR `display: inline-block`)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Answered here in [the official W3 specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/) under [**transformable element**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#terminology):

> an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is
>   either a **block-level** or **atomic inline-level element**, or whose
>   ‘display’ property computes to ‘table-row’, ‘table-row-group’,
>   ‘table-header-group’, ‘table-footer-group’, ‘table-cell’, or
>   ‘table-caption’ [CSS21]

Comment: so the documentation does't explicitly mention what `display` values , it ignors ! ?

Answer (score 8):

The updated version of [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-property) says:

> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - all elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model except for **non-replaced inline boxes**, table-column boxes, and table-column-group boxes [CSS2],
> - all SVG paint server elements, the clipPath element and SVG renderable elements with the exception of any descendant element of text content elements [SVG2].

We should note that not all the `inline` elements cannot be transformed but only the *non-replaced inline* elements thus the *replaced inline* elements can be transformed.

So basically we can apply transformation to `img`, `canvas`, etc without the need of making them `inline-block` or `block`

```js
var all = document.querySelectorAll('.replaced');

for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++) {
 console.log(window.getComputedStyle(all[i],null).getPropertyValue("display"));
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background:red;
}

.replaced {
  transform:rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=1069" class="replaced">
<canvas class="replaced"></canvas>
```

More details about replaced elements:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#replaced-elements

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element

[what is a non-replaced inline element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12468176/8620333)