# CSS3 translate() method

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<style>
span
{
width:200px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
border:1px solid black;
}
span.c2
{
transform:translate(50px,100px);
-ms-transform:translate(50px,100px); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:translate(50px,100px); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
</style>

<span class="c2">Hello. This is a DIV element.</span>
```

The problem is `translate` method is not getting applied to `<span>` element. Also the **width and height** specified for `<span>` element is not working.

What is the reason?

Comment: sorry i was thinking about the transform3d method caniuse.com/transforms3d

Comment: @Rachel Gallen no probs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work, you need to have `display: block;` for `span` element as `span` element is inline, it won't translate the `span` element unless you make it `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KYwxn/)

[Related Question Of Mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/does-css-transform-property-works-on-block-and-inline-block-level-elements-only)

Comment: do u mean it dont apply for inline element .

Comment: Alein what about height and weidth .I was taught every element has these two properties

Comment: @Maizere Yes it won't, here's my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/does-css-transform-property-works-on-block-and-inline-block-level-elements-only

Comment: A more complete explanation would be nice. Here are some references to start with: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform and http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#annotation_definitions (Ctrl+F "transformable element").

Comment: @Mr.Alien but image is also an inline element why width and height for it

Comment: @Maizere We had attributes of height and width for `img` tag, and not for `span` :)