# Flip horizontally html and css

Tags: html, css, extjs, flip

I am trying to implement a feature where I need to have two trees, one next to the other, looking like mirrors. Please, see the image:

[image]

The point is I found the way to flip it horizontally but text is also inverted. What I cannot do is invert the tree letting the text as it is.

Here is what I have done: http://jsfiddle.net/lontivero/R24mA/

Basically, the following class is applied to the html body:

```css
.flip-horizontal {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-filter: fliph; /*IE*/
    filter: fliph; /*IE*/
}
```

The HTML code:

```html
<body class="flip-horizontal"></body>
```

And the JS:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    // more and more code. SO forces me to paste js code ;(
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: why dont' you just align everything to the right?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your fiddle already had the start of the answer - to do a second flip on the text. There was an extra `,` preventing the second rule from being parsed.

[I've updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R24mA/1/) to include the heading elements, and set them to `inline-block` because [inline elements can't be transformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/does-css-transform-property-works-on-block-and-inline-block-level-elements-only).

```css
.flip-horizontal, .x-grid-cell-inner, .x-column-header-text, .x-panel-header-text {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-filter: fliph; /*IE*/
    filter: fliph; /*IE*/
}

.x-column-header-text, .x-panel-header-text {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This is all well and good until you click on a record to edit it `:P`

Comment: Ahh, I didn't check that before. I guess it's just a case of having to track down all the text classes and add them to the flip selector.

Answer (score 4):

I tried this, and it works great!

HTML code:

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            <!-- Front content -->
        </div>

        <div class="back">
            <!-- Back content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
/* Flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}

/* Flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* Hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* Front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;

    /* For Firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* Back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

I use this inside a Bootstrap `col-sm-*` and works great too:

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="content-box flipper">
        <div class="content-box-front">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope content-box-icon"></span>
            <h4>Share your emotions</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="content-box-back">
            <p>Share emotions with friends, family and teammates.</p>
            <button>Read more</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the CSS:

```css
.content-box {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 105px;
    width: 100%;
}

.content-box-icon {
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto 15px auto;
    color: #fff;
    float: none; 
    background:#25acfd                     
}

.content-box-front
{
    z-index: 2;

    /* For Firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);

    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px;
}

.content-box-back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 105px;
}

/* Entire container, keeps perspective */

/* Flip the pane when hovered */
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* Flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Rotating round 180deg is not the same as flipping (the element will be upside down with rotation).

Comment: @fredrivett Rotating only the Y with `transform: rotateY(180deg)` will not turn the element upside down.

Comment: @avisk damn, I didn't know this, you're right, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [example](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/reversing-text/):

```
/* Entire text flipped around */
div {
  -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```