# GreenSock Animations on span elements

Tags: html, css, gsap

Iam Performing simple Greensock animations, Iam unable to perform any animation on span elements..even any animation i performed its just blinking can any one help. Is there any problem with my span elements defining.

Here is the code.

```
<div id="prac">
    <div><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span></div>
  </div>
```

CSS Style

```
#prac span{padding:20px;border:1px dashed blue;background:violet;margin:5px;}
```

JS
`TweenMax.staggerFrom($("#prac").find("span"), 0.4, {scale:0, rotation:-360, autoAlpha:0},` 0.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make your `span` a `block` or `inline-block` as it is `inline` by default, and hence, it fails to animate.

[Related Question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/does-css-transform-property-works-on-block-and-inline-block-level-elements-only)

Answer (score 0):

SPAN elements are styled as "inline" by default and won't move independent of their parent element.

You need to set the "display" property in the CSS to either "block" or "inline-block".

Try this:

```
#prac span{padding:20px;border:1px dashed blue;background:violet;margin:5px;display:block}
```

Or alternatively, you could change from a SPAN to a DIV.