# Statically rotate font-awesome icons

Tags: css, rotation, font-awesome

I'd like to statically rotate my font-awesome icons by 45 degrees. It says on the site that:

> To arbitrarily rotate and flip icons, use the fa-rotate-* and fa-flip-* classes.

However, doing

```
<i class="fa fa-link fa-rotate-45" style="font-size:1.5em"></i>
```

does not work, whereas replacing `fa-rotate-45` with `fa-rotate-90` does. Does this mean that they in fact cannot rotate arbitrarily?

Comment: Use `tax-shadow`. Reference: https://code2real.blogspot.com/2021/03/how-to-make-text-unreadable-using-css.html

Answer (score 250, accepted):

**Before FontAwesome 5:**

The standard declarations just contain `.fa-rotate-90`, `.fa-rotate-180` and `.fa-rotate-270`.
However you can easily create your own:

```
.fa-rotate-45 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

**With FontAwesome 5:**

You can use what’s so called “Power Transforms”. Example:

```
<i class="fas fa-snowman" data-fa-transform="rotate-90"></i>
<i class="fas fa-snowman" data-fa-transform="rotate-180"></i>
<i class="fas fa-snowman" data-fa-transform="rotate-270"></i>
<i class="fas fa-snowman" data-fa-transform="rotate-30"></i>
<i class="fas fa-snowman" data-fa-transform="rotate--30"></i>
```

You need to add the `data-fa-transform` attribute with the value of `rotate-` and your desired rotation in degrees.

Source: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/power-transforms

Comment: matches Font Awesome's naming conventions; nice!

Comment: Don't forget to also change display property of icon from "inline" to "inline-block". The transform will not work on inline elements. [More in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements)

Comment: We can do it use `fa-flip-horizontal` class. Reference: https://code2real.blogspot.com/2019/03/how-to-flip-font-awesome-icons.html

Answer (score 17):

New Font-Awesome **v5** has **Power Transforms**

You can rotate any icon by adding attribute `data-fa-transform` to icon

```
<i class="fas fa-magic" data-fa-transform="rotate-45"></i>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dt2m49vh/1/)

For more information, check this out : [Font-Awesome5 Power Tranforms](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/power-transforms)

Answer (score 15):

In case someone else stumbles upon this question and wants it here is the SASS mixin I use.

```
@mixin rotate($deg: 90){
    $sDeg: #{$deg}deg;

    -webkit-transform: rotate($sDeg);
    -moz-transform: rotate($sDeg);
    -ms-transform: rotate($sDeg);
    -o-transform: rotate($sDeg);
    transform: rotate($sDeg);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to rotate 45 degrees, you can use the CSS transform property:

```
.fa-rotate-45 {
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);     /* Internet Explorer 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform:rotate(45deg);         /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
<i class="fa fa-power-off text-gray" style="transform: rotate(90deg);"></i>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28stylesheet_language%29) you can directly use the following mixin:

```
.@{fa-css-prefix}-rotate-90  { .fa-icon-rotate(90deg, 1);  }
```