# Why can't inline elements be transformed?

Tags: css, css-transforms, w3c

[The CSS transformations spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element) says transforms only work on block-level or atomic inline-level elements (e.g. `inline-block`). But **why** don't they work on inline elements? What is the reasoning behind this limitation?

[This test](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/ietestcenter/css3/transforms/transform-002.htm) by Microsoft shows it's possible. It passes in IE9, but not in Chrome. So it's possible, just not by the spec.

Comment: This is not a valid question.

Comment: Seems a perfectly valid question to me.

Comment: You are asking: why css is the way it is?

Comment: Always have a reason

Comment: @Kristine, which is not disallowed.  There's a *reason* C# doesn't have the concept of `const`.  It's a good question to find these things out if they are non-obvious.

Comment: Is this really the place for such a question?

Comment: @Kristine: If the answer tends to be on the lines of *because W3C decided so* then it is not on topic but I am sure there is a reason behind why `inline` elements cant be transformed and so it remains on topic.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clearing that up. I would ask this elsewhere.

Comment: I suspect it is because they have no intrinsic dimensions, so there's nothing to transform.

Comment: @Shikkediel but they have calculated dimensions, just like a block element with `height: auto`, right? And they have a position you could translate.

Comment: Just offering a clue there... usually when I try to go through the spec finding the exact answer to a question like this, I end up with "well, this is just how they defined it". Inline boxes can be weird in my experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS transform doesn't work on inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Shikkediel mentioned, inline elements do not have strong boundary like block elements do. They don't influence the flow of the document in the same way, if at all, and are tightly bound to their neighboring text or elements. CSS transforms operate on the bounding box (which inline elements do technically have) in a way that wouldn't really make sense for inline elements.

Consider a `<strong>` within a `<span>` (or div). The bold text is defined only by the change in style, but can flow across multiple lines and does not have a predictable rectangular bounding area. If you were to apply a CSS rotation, where would it rotate from? How would it reflow, if at all, while rotating?

On the other hand, the containing `<span>` does have rectangular bounds, so finding the center and corners, rotating and scaling, are all predictable and well-defined.

As an example, take [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cq8rrr5y/). The background of the inline element is:

[image: inline strong with background color]

but the bounds shown by the editor are:

[image: inline strong with debugger hightlight]

You can clearly see that the background and the element's bounds do not match at all. Without clear bounds, transforms because difficult and not very useful.

Comment: I'm thinking since for instance Chrome dev tools shows you a kind of bounding box for inline elements when you select them and it would be trivial to transform that box, even if it is not rectangular. In fact, this test from Microsoft is for transforming an inline element. It passes on IE9, but not on Chrome. So it's definitely possible, just not by the spec. http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/ietestcenter/css3/transforms/transform-002.htm

Comment: @Tetaxa The box is forced to be a rectangle, though. It's the smallest rectangle that encompasses the content of the element, which makes it a very unpredictable size and shape. As you can see from the images I added, it might not match the visual shape of the element at all (and doesn't even match the parent in this case). That makes it useless for transforms, since the transform would change depending on the user's font settings and every other small factor.

Comment: I think you're on to the why. I strongly disagree that it would be useless however. A rotation would be difficult, but translation would work just fine. I also don't see how the user's font settings etc affecting the bounding box is any different from a block element with auto height or float, both of which can be transformed just fine.

Comment: How are you supposed to apply predictable (well-styled) transforms to an unpredictable box? It's possible to apply transforms to partially dynamic block elements, but at least then the bounds match what you see. The actual bounds of an inline element and the visual boundaries are mostly unrelated.

Comment: Like I said, translations should be easy. Like this (open in Chrome) https://jsfiddle.net/296nnenf/ Scale and rotate is hard, I agree. Thanks for taking the time with this though, it's been bothering me.