# ReactCSSTransitionGroup not animating properly for transform translate

Tags: css, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I have no trouble adding animation between route. But when I try something simple as follow:

```
var IntroSection = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    return(

      <div id = "intro">

      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="introFirst" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={1300}>
        <span key={"hello"}>  Hello, </span>
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>

     [...]
    </div>
```

css:

```
  .introFirst-appear{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-250px);
    transition: opacity 10s linear;
  }

  .introFirst-appear.introFirst-appear-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform:translateX(0px);
  }
```

Opacity part works perfectly, but the translateX part doesnt work at all. Nothing moved.

the css for the div `#intro`, doesnt have anything special, only `font`, `text-align`, `width`, `float:right`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only specifying that opacity should be animated with the transition rule. Alos, according to [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14883287/321575), the transform property only applies to block level elements. Try doing this:

```
.introFirst-appear {
     /*...*/
     display: inline-block;
     transition: opacity 10s linear, transform 10s linear;
}
```

Comment: o i actually used `ALL` in my code before, which didnt work either. Since I have translateX(-250px) it should start at -250px anyways right? but it doesnt, it stayed where it is from start til end

Comment: what happens if you add the `transform: translateX(-250px);` rule to the element using dev tools?

Comment: dev tools as in the thing on chrome where you right click and choose 'inspect' right? I tried it and nothing changed. If I put left: -250px nothing happen either unless i put position relative

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean by dev tools. Also updated my answer with some more information about the `display` property.