# TranslateX to appear as animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying to use more css and less Javascript for animation. I am running into an issue animating three different boxes. I have the boxes fade in with opacity by adding the `fadeShow` class to bring the opacity to 1. However, I am wanting the boxes to appear as if they are animating from the left side of the page to the right.

Here is a fiddle that shows it in action:

[Click here to see](http://jsfiddle.net/5Zs6F/203/)

```
.info-box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #00f;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 100px;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.info-box.fadeShow {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(150px);
}
```

I am trying to make the boxes animate over 150px OR if there is a better way to do this to put the boxes into their perminent state. What I mean by this is, if the boxes are supposed to be at `left: 25%;`, `left: 45%;` and `left: 65%;`, then I would want the boxes to be 150px to the left of that and then transition into place.

Comment: You can't transform inline elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) and [calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
    
    var top, green, red, yellow;
  
    top = this.scrollY;
  
    green = document.querySelector("#green"),
    red   = document.querySelector("#red"),
    yellow= document.querySelector("#yellow");
    
    if(top > 100){
      green.classList.add("green", "active");
      red.classList.add("red", "active");
      yellow.classList.add("yellow", "active");
    }
}, false);
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; height: 400vh}
body{margin: 0; padding-top: 200px}

.box{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  opacity:0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-150px);
  opacity:0
}

#green{
  background: green;
  left: 25%;
}
#red{
  background: red;
  left: 45%;
}
#yellow{
  background: yellow;
  left: 65%;
}
#green.green{transition: all .3s ease}
#red.red{transition: all .6s ease}
#yellow.yellow{transition: all .9s ease}

#green.active,
#red.active,
#yellow.active{opacity: 1;transform: translateX(0);}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <div id=green class=box></div>
    <div id=red class=box></div>
    <div id=yellow class=box></div>
  </article>
</section>
```

With [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) and [calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box}
body{margin: 0; padding-top: 20px}

.box{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute
}

#green{
  background: green;
  left: 25%;
  animation:slideinGreen .3s ease
}
#red{
  background: red;
  left: 45%;
  animation:slideinRed .6s ease
}
#yellow{
  background: yellow;
  left: 65%;
  animation:slideinYellow .9s ease
}
@keyframes slideinGreen {
  from {
    left: calc(25% - 150px); opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes slideinRed{
  from {
    left: calc(45% - 150px); opacity: 0
  }
}
@keyframes slideinYellow {
  from {
    left: calc(65% - 150px); opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <div id=green class=box></div>
    <div id=red class=box></div>
    <div id=yellow class=box></div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Now you can add [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
    
    var top, green, red, yellow;
  
    top = this.scrollY;
  
    green = document.querySelector("#green"),
    red   = document.querySelector("#red"),
    yellow= document.querySelector("#yellow");
    
    if(top > 100){
      green.classList.add("green", "active");
      red.classList.add("red", "active");
      yellow.classList.add("yellow", "active");
    }
}, false);
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; height: 400vh}
body{margin: 0; padding-top: 200px}

.box{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  opacity:0;
  position: absolute
}

#green{
  background: green;
  left: 25%;
}
#red{
  background: red;
  left: 45%;
}
#yellow{
  background: yellow;
  left: 65%;
}
#green.green{animation:slideinGreen .3s ease}
#red.red{animation:slideinRed .6s ease}
#yellow.yellow{animation:slideinYellow .9s ease}
#green.active,#red.active,#yellow.active{opacity: 1}
@keyframes slideinGreen {
  from {
    left: calc(25% - 150px);opacity:0
  }
}
@keyframes slideinRed{
  from {
    left: calc(45% - 150px);opacity:0
  }
}
@keyframes slideinYellow {
  from {
    left: calc(65% - 150px);opacity:0
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <div id=green class=box></div>
    <div id=red class=box></div>
    <div id=yellow class=box></div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: This is perfect. I am just tryng to figure out how to make these keyframes not begin until I am to the waypoint,

Comment: set classes when in viewpoint add them to divs i will update it.

Comment: I have this so far, but it isn't working. https://jsfiddle.net/99r4rk9j/1/ .... I tried adding `display: none` to the box class and then using `show()` in my waypoint to show/initiate it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, to have the boxes slide over from the left, you should apply the negative transformation to the `.info-box` class:

```
transform:translatex(-150px);
```

And then reset it in the `.fadeShow` class:

```
transform:initial;
```

Secondly, you have the `display` property of the `.info-box` class set to `inline`, you'll need to change that as transformations can't be applied to inline elements.

Finally, for performance purposes, it's best to explicitly state which properties you want to apply transitions to:

```
transition:opacity 1s,transform 1s;
```

Or:

```
transition-duration:1s;
transition-property:opacity,transform;
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I get each box to fadeIn at different times?

Comment: That should be posted as a new question as it is beyond the scope of what you have asked here but you could create a new class for each, giving them their own `transition-delay` and/or `transition-duration`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set css transition to: transition: all 1s;
since you need to tell what properties you need to animate.
and using all means animate all css properties. also you need to set display: inline-block

```
.info-box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #00f;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 100px;
  transition:all 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything differently.

Comment: I edited your code run the new code and scroll down to run the animation

Comment: Thanks. How would I get each box to fadeIn at different times?

Comment: in css you have two different ways to animate things: using transition, or using animation and keyframes. you cant make them fadein in different times using only css transitions. you need to use css animations and key frames or javascript to do that checkout these links
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp
http://greensock.com/

Answer (score 1):

The transform isn't working because the child divs are set to `display:inline`.

Change that to `inline-block`.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j5h7Lpzc/2/)

Comment: Thanks. How would I get each box to fadeIn at different times?

Comment: That's more complex. You'd have to apply, I guess a different transition-delay on each one. I think that's right.