# CSS transition is not working with anchor tag

Tags: html, css

While working with CSS transition, I see the second block (with class "link1") is not working, but the first block (with class "link") is working. I'm trying to zoom in the text inside anchor tag on hover.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.link {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.link:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.link1 {
  color: black;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.link1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<!-- It works.-->
<div class="link"></div>
<br/>

<!-- It does not work-->
<a href=""><span class="link1"><strong>Facebook</strong></span></a>
```

Comment: I'm assuming `scale` does not work on inline elements. Try to apply `.link1 { display: inline-block; }`.

Comment: Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements

Comment: @connexo:Yeah It worked ! Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `scale` does not work on inline elements, in this scenario the `span.link1`. Apply

`.link1 { display: inline-block; }`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .link{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
       transition: all .5s ease-in-out; 
    }
    
    .link:hover {
       transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    
    .link1{
     
        color:black;
        display: inline-block;
        transition: all .5s ease-in-out;   
    }
    .link1:hover{
        transform: scale(1.2); 
    }
    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <!-- It works.-->
    <div class="link"></div><br/>
    
    <!-- It does not work-->
    <a href=""> <span class="link1"><strong>Facebook</strong></span></a>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```