# CSS Transition doesn't work with a hyperlink but works with a div, why?

Tags: css, frontend

**Kinda solved.**

I have 3 buttons, 1 of them is a div and 2 of them are links. In other aspects they are absolutely the same.
Transition on the div `id = "portfolio_button"` works properly, and for some reason it doesn't work on the hyperlinks `id = "blogbtn"` and `id = "ordenbtn"`. But they are identical. Please tell me why it doesn't work there? Transition doesn't work only on `class="point"` divs. So, mainly I just need to smoothly change their color and add a box-shadow.

Moreover, if I load the page, it doesn't work, but sometimes, I wait like 2-3 minutes, or reload the page 2-3 times and it starts to work properly.

PS: I've noticed, the transition works good with the `box-shadow`, but doesn't work only with the `background-color`.

PS2: Ok, a strange thing, I have just changed the point divs to SVGs and it has solved the problem.

```css
   .animation_fast
    {
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition:    all .3s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition:      all .3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition:     all .3s ease-in-out;
        transition:         all .3s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .three_menu_btn
    {
        font-size: 15px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        width:33.33%;
        height:33.33vw;
        background-color: rgb(12,12,12);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center;
    }
    
    .three_menu_btn p
    {
        color: rgb(222,222,222);
    }
    
    .three_menu_btn:hover
    {
        background-color: rgb(2,2,2);
    }
    
    .three_menu_btn:hover p
    {
        color: rgb(0,168,89);
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgb(0,168,89);
    }
    
    .three_menu_btn:hover .point
    {
        background-color: rgb(0,168,89);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,168,89,0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,168,89,0.5);
        -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,168,89,0.5);
        -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,168,89,0.5);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,168,89,0.5);
    }
    
    .points
    {
        height:auto;
        width:auto;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
    .point
    {
        margin:5px;
        display:block;
        float:left;
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: rgb(222,222,222);
    }
```

```html
<section id = "section2">
        <div id = "portfolio_button" class = "three_menu_btn animation_fast" >
            <div class = "points">
                <div class = "point animation_fast">
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class = "animation_fast">Our Portfolio</p>
        </div>
        
        <a id = "blogbtn" class = "three_menu_btn animation_fast" href = "{% url 'blog' %}">
            <div class = "points">
                <div class = "point animation_fast">
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class = "animation_fast">Our Blog</p>
        </a>
        
        <a id = "ordenbtn" class = "three_menu_btn animation_fast" href = "{% url 'contact' %}">
            <div class = "points">
                <div class = "point animation_fast">
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class = "animation_fast">Make an order</p>
        </a>
</section>
```

I am looking forward to your help! Thanks!

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38925825/css-transition-is-not-working-with-anchor-tag). I would check to see if changing those two anchor elements to `display: inline-block` or another setting may unlock the ability for those effects to be applicable to the elements.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @krillgar, I will try now, But I read it, it says there that the cause is the `display: inline` In my case it is `display: flex`.

Comment: Ultimately, your issue could just come down to something simple like "anchor tags don't have the properties you're trying to manipulate like a div does." Doing something like changing the `display` can _help_ get it closer, but if you're using `flex` because of other display properties, there's a possibility that you'll be missing out on this. (Yes, I am going for more of a "generic" answer than specifically what you're looking for, as that is the point of the site. However, hopefully the _why_ is making sense for you.)

Comment: @krillgar, Yeah, thank you. It makes sense. I'll try to change it to `display: block` now and will say if it helps. ) Thanks!

Comment: @krillgar, nah, it hasn't helped.

Comment: What you can do to maintain flex is to wrap the anchor in a div that has `display: flex`. But then at that point, why not just eliminate the anchor tag all together? ;)

Comment: @krillgar, Yeah, I already has tried to remove `flex` at all. But it hasn't helped. The problem persists.

Comment: It's not clear from the text alone what the problem is. When I run the snippet, all three hover transitions are running identically [In Chrome Version 109.0.5414.74 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 11]. If you are seeing something different, please be explicit about what those differences are, and what platform/browser combinations you are seeing them on. Also, you don't have any buttons; you have divs and anchor elements dressed up like buttons, which may be part of the problem.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, yeah, indeed, I have just run the snippet too and it works perfectly here. Don't know why it didn't work on my website. There were no transition between the start and the end of the animation. But I've changed divs to SVGs where there is no `background-color` but just a `color` and it solved the problem.