# Why isn't this text rotated?

Tags: css

I've tried quite a few variants with no luck. What am I missing?

```css
#menu {
 position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 height: 250px;
 top: 15px;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #ee2e24;
 color: white;
}
#menu span {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 transform-origin: left top 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"><span>MAIN MENU</span></div>
```

Comment: Is that preprocessor CSS, like less or sass?

Comment: Sorry, it was LESS, fixed the snippet.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [text-orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation).

```css
#menu {
 position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 height: 250px;
 top: 15px;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #ee2e24;
 color: white;
}
#menu span {
 writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: sideways;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"><span>MAIN MENU</span></div>
```

Comment: This cured my cancer.  How compatible is it?

Comment: Not so much i'm afraid (it seems to be only spported by Firefox at the moment). Sorry.

Comment: But it seems that you should be abel to do the same according to this article : https://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-text

Comment: @Scott https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation#Browser_compatibility <<- Seems to be a bit outdated: Here is more info in the caniuse issue queue: https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/2077

Comment: It works in Chrome/Webkit which is all I need.  Thank you!

Comment: "This is an experimental technology
Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the specification changes." From https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation#Quick_Links

Answer (score 4):

You need to add  `display:inline-block;` to the span

```css
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 250px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ee2e24;
  color: white;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  /*transform-origin: left top 0;*/
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"><span>MAIN MENU</span></div>
```

Comment: padding/margin?

Comment: @mplungjan you can use padding and margin :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot use LESS or SCSS in the SA snippets. Just pure CSS, so move `span` out of `#menu`
2. `span` is an inline element. You cannot transform inline elements. Make span a block element with `display: block`

```css
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 250px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ee2e24;
  color: white;
}
#menu span {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"><span>MAIN MENU</span></div>
```