# :after pseudo element animation working in IE & Firefox, not Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

Using the Divi Theme for Wordpress

What I'm trying to do is animated the dandelion image (see snippet). The animation works fine in IE and FireFox, but it is not working in Chrome.

The image is replacing a font-icon, which is the '7' wrapped in the `span` element. I initially replaced the span's content with the dandelion image, but the `content` URL would not show up in Firefox. I have to have the "click to scroll' text in a `:before` pseudo element, which is why I had to use the `:after` pseudo element.

I should note that I don't have the ability to manually change what is inside the `span` element, I have to use CSS to override it's contents.

What can I do to get the animation to work in Chrome?

Live version: http://gardenviewcare.wpengine.com/adult-day-center/

```css
.et_pb_fullwidth_header .et_pb_fullwidth_header_scroll a:before {
  content: "click to scroll";
  display: block;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

span.scroll-down.et-pb-icon {
  display: none;
}

.et_pb_fullwidth_header .et_pb_fullwidth_header_scroll a:after {
  content: url('http://gardenviewcare.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/dandelion-icon.png') !important;
  animation: swing 15s linear infinite;
  transform: rotate(0);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

@keyframes swing {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateX(15deg) rotateY(15deg) rotateZ(15deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(-20deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateX(15deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(-15deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-10deg) rotateY(-5deg);
  }
}


/** just for snippet sake so you can see the icon, as it is white **/

body {
  background: #60bb46;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://gardenviewcare.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Divi-child-01/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://gardenviewcare.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Divi/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="et_pb_fullwidth_header et_pb_section_parallax et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_dark et_pb_text_align_center  et_pb_fullwidth_header_0">

  <div class="et_pb_fullwidth_header_scroll" style="opacity: 1;"><a href="#"><span class="scroll-down et-pb-icon">7</span></a></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: block` to the `::after` element.

The [official W3 specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/) defines a [**transformable element**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#terminology) as:

> an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is
>   either a **block-level** or **atomic inline-level element**, or whose
>   ‘display’ property computes to ‘table-row’, ‘table-row-group’,
>   ‘table-header-group’, ‘table-footer-group’, ‘table-cell’, or
>   ‘table-caption’ [CSS21]

(Borrowed from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14883287/4573410)

```css
.et_pb_fullwidth_header .et_pb_fullwidth_header_scroll a:before {
  content: "click to scroll";
  display: block;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 80px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

span.scroll-down.et-pb-icon {
  display: none;
}

.et_pb_fullwidth_header .et_pb_fullwidth_header_scroll a:after {
  content: url('http://gardenviewcare.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/dandelion-icon.png') !important;
  animation: swing 15s linear infinite;
  transform: rotate(0);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: block;
}

@keyframes swing {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateX(15deg) rotateY(15deg) rotateZ(15deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(-20deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateX(15deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(-15deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-10deg) rotateY(-5deg);
  }
}


/** just for snippet sake so you can see the icon, as it is white **/

body {
  background: #60bb46;
}
```

```html
<section class="et_pb_fullwidth_header et_pb_section_parallax et_pb_module et_pb_bg_layout_dark et_pb_text_align_center  et_pb_fullwidth_header_0">

  <div class="et_pb_fullwidth_header_scroll" style="opacity: 1;"><a href="#"><span class="scroll-down et-pb-icon">7</span></a></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and precise answer!