# CSS Animation not working when wrapped with another element

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have the following HTML and CSS animation, and works as is expected.

```css
app-root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}

body {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.loading h1 {
  color: #272C33;

  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: -apple-system,
    "BlinkMacSystemFont",
    "Segoe UI",
    "Roboto",
    "Oxygen-Sans",
    "Ubuntu",
    "Cantarell",
    "Helvetica",
    sans-serif;

  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes dots {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.d {
  animation: dots 2.0s ease-out infinite;
}
.d-2 {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.d-3 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<app-root>
  Loading<span class="d">.</span><span class="d d-2">.</span><span class="d d-3">.</span>
</app-root>
```

But, when the *"loading"* portion is wrapped with a `div` and `H1`, the animation doesn't work anymore.

```css
app-root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}

body {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.loading h1 {
  color: #272C33;

  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: -apple-system,
    "BlinkMacSystemFont",
    "Segoe UI",
    "Roboto",
    "Oxygen-Sans",
    "Ubuntu",
    "Cantarell",
    "Helvetica",
    sans-serif;

  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes dots {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.d {
  animation: dots 2.0s ease-out infinite;
}
.d-2 {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.d-3 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<app-root>
  <div class="loading">
    <h1>Loading<span class="d">.</span><span class="d d-2">.</span><span class="d d-3">.</span></h1>
  </div>
</app-root>
```

Is my CSS for the animation in the wrong place/specified incorrectly because of the wrapping elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS transforms [doesn't work on inline text elements](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#terminology). You need to set `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to `.d`:

```
.d {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: dots 2.0s ease-out infinite;
}
```

Example:

```css
app-root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}

body {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.loading h1 {
  color: #272C33;

  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: -apple-system,
    "BlinkMacSystemFont",
    "Segoe UI",
    "Roboto",
    "Oxygen-Sans",
    "Ubuntu",
    "Cantarell",
    "Helvetica",
    sans-serif;

  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes dots {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.d {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: dots 2.0s ease-out infinite;
}
.d-2 {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.d-3 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<app-root>
  <div class="loading">
    <h1>Loading<span class="d">.</span><span class="d d-2">.</span><span class="d d-3">.</span></h1>
  </div>
</app-root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is why:

[CSS transform doesn't work on inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements?answertab=active#tab-top)

To solve it, set `.d` has `inline-block` element.

```
.d {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: dots 2.0s ease-out infinite;
}
```

```css
app-root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}

body {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.loading h1 {
  color: #272C33;

  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: -apple-system,
    "BlinkMacSystemFont",
    "Segoe UI",
    "Roboto",
    "Oxygen-Sans",
    "Ubuntu",
    "Cantarell",
    "Helvetica",
    sans-serif;

  text-align: center;
}

@keyframes dots {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.d {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: dots 2.0s ease-out infinite;
}
.d-2 {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.d-3 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

```html
<app-root>
  <div class="loading">
    <h1>Loading<span class="d">.</span><span class="d d-2">.</span><span class="d d-3">.</span></h1>
  </div>
</app-root>
```