# CSS Scale element without affecting :after pseudo-element

Tags: css, css-transforms, pseudo-element

I would like to scale an element without affecting its pseudo-element (:after). Is that possible?
The following link demonstrates what I am trying to accomplish:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: .2s all cubic-bezier(.250, .460, .450, .940);
}

li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

li:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '•';
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

'dot' is scaled with the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the pseudo element is applied to `li` you can simply scale the `a`. Don't forget to make it at least `inline-block` as [the transformation won't work with inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements).

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .2s all cubic-bezier(.250, .460, .450, .940);
}

li:hover a {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

li:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '•';
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
  <li><a>Hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Damnit! I should have come with that by myself. Don't even know why I applied transformation to li. Thanks.