# HTML <thead> Text Rotation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a **table header**.

[image]

The **HTML** `th` elements which in `thead` are defined as follows:

```
<th>
    <span class="rotate-all">期數</span>
</th>
<th>
    <span class="rotate-all">位置</span>
</th>
<th>
    <span class="rotate-all">設置容量 (kWp)</span>
</th>
<th>
    <span class="rotate-all">2016年</span>
</th>
<!-- omit -->
```

I am trying to rotate the `span` in `th` with **90-degrees**, but still can't rotate `span` via CSS.

**Details:**

Render HTML views with Javascript:

```
var makeTable = function (tableId, className, headerArray, contentArray) {
    return "<table class='" + className + "' id='" + tableId + "'>" + makeHeader(headerArray) + makeContentTr(contentArray) + "</table>";
}
var makeHeader = function (headerArray) {
    if (headerArray != undefined && headerArray != null && headerArray != "") {
        return "<thead><tr>" + makeHeaderContent(headerArray) + "</tr></thead>";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
};
var makeHeaderContent = function (headerArray) {
    var header = [];
    //Add an empty header to the first column if selectColumn option is true
    if (selectColumn) {
        headerArray = headerArray.slice();
        //Adds new items to the beginning of an array
        headerArray.unshift("<input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"select-all\" />");
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < headerArray.length; i++) {
        //Adds new items to the end of an array
        header.push("<th><span class=\"rotate-all\">" + headerArray[i] + "</span></th>");
    }
    return header.join(""); //Joins the elements of an array into a string
}
```

CSS Code:

```
.rotate-all{
    /* FF3.5+ */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
    /* Opera 10.5 */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
    /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
    /* IE6,IE7 */
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);
    /* IE8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)";
    /* Standard */
    transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
    color:yellow;
}
```

What do I need to change in the CSS to make this work?

Comment: apply `display:inline-block` to `span` tag....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `transform` property does not apply to inline elements, as stated here: [CSS transform doesn't work on inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements)

```
.rotate-all {
    display: block;
}
```