# Why isn't my text moving when scrolling in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a parallax effect on the scroll. "Po Ta To" have to scroll at different speeds. however it isn't working.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {

  const target = document.querySelectorAll('.parallax');
  var index = 0,
    length = target.length;

  for (index; index < length; index++) {
    var pos = window.pageYOffset * target[index].dataset.speed;
    target[index].style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + pos + 'px, 0px)';
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  height: 200vh;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  height: 30vh;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li class="parallax" data-speed="2">PO</li>
    <li class="parallax" data-speed="1.5">TA</li>
    <li class="parallax" data-speed="2.3">TO</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS transform doesn't work on inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements) Short answer, it doesn't work because the `li` aren't a `display: block`

Comment: Here is a working example on your code:
https://codepen.io/hac/pen/JjjXKPO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transform` isn't working properly on your `li` elements because they are `inline`.  They need to be some kind of `block` to work properly.

See here with `inline-block`.  I've obviously had to set a width on them to stop them taking up the full width of the page:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  const target = document.querySelectorAll('.parallax');
  var index = 0,
    length = target.length;

  for (index; index < length; index++) {
    var pos = window.pageYOffset * target[index].dataset.speed;
    target[index].style.transform = 'translateY(' + pos + 'px)';
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  height: 200vh;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  height: 30vh;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li class="parallax" data-speed="2">PO</li>
    <li class="parallax" data-speed="1.5">TA</li>
    <li class="parallax" data-speed="2.3">TO</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Tweak as necessary to achieve the desired effect.