# Achieve position sticky content at exact center?

Tags: html, css

Here is a span that is sticky and I tried to place it exactly at the center of the document but I don't want to give margin-left or left because it does not give the exact center of the document.

So Is there any way to get an exact center with position sticky.?

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 50%;
}
p{
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sticky Element</h2>
<span class="sticky">I am from sticky</span>
<p>Some example text..</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `display: inline-block` ([?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements)) and `transform: translateX(-50%)` to horizontal center your element.

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
p {
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sticky Element</h2>
<span class="sticky">I am from sticky</span>

<p>Some example text..</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using display: table property:

```css
.sticky {
    position: sticky; 
    top: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sticky Element</h2>
<span class="sticky">I am from sticky</span>

<p>Some example text..</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sticky {
    position: sticky; 
    top: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sticky Element</h2>
<span class="sticky">I am from sticky</span>

<p>Some example text..</p>
```

Comment: thankful for advanced full with a examples nice !

Comment: hi @agile, welcome to SO, always add comments, notes, or descriptions to your answer, only a snippet may solve the problem, but a description gives more knowledge, read here more about how to answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer