# a:hover doesn't register || @keyframes

Tags: css, sass

Learning SCSS /CSS

Attempting to animate an `<a>`**:hover** with `@keyframes`.

When `SCSS` compiles, `style.css` doesn't get the `<a>:hover` lines of code, but the `at keyframes are showing up.

**Tried** placing the `a:hover` inside of the `a`tag in `SCSS` and the compilation is the same result.

Please see Codepen below (top of CSS page is filled with reset code, **please scroll down** to `.nav`)

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/sltdev/pen/ZEGBqPr?editors=1100)

Below is the actual `SCSS`

```
`.nav {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
height: 100px;
background-color: #ecdfc8;`


&__img{
    flex: 1 1 10%;

}

img{
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}

&__section{
    flex: 8 1 90%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

&__ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

&__ul--lf{
    width: 50%;
}

&__ul--rt{
    width: 15%;
}

&__item{
    //display: flex;

}

a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    @include btn($px, $px1);
    animation-name: grow;
    animation-duration: 4 hus;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;



}

&:hover{
    @keyframes grow {
        0%{
            transform: scale(1);
        }
        100%{
            transform: scale(2);
            background-color: #fff;
        }
    }
}
}
```

`

Comment: How does it make any sense at all to define `@keyframes` on `:hover`? That is the reasons SCSS deletes that part.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14883250/8620333 .. you cannot apply transform to links without display:inline-block at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is the animation to run on `a:hover` inside `.nav`, you need to define the keyframes outside of that block and apply the actual animation rules inside the `:hover` block:

```
.nav {
    a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 300;
        &:hover {
            animation-name: grow;
            animation-duration: 4 hus;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }
    }
}

@keyframes grow {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(2);
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}
```

This compiles to

```css
.nav a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.nav a:hover {
  animation-name: grow;
  animation-duration: 4 hus;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code pen this is how it should be written

```
.nav a {    
    //css property goes here
   &:hover{
     // Hover animation goes here
   }    
}
```