# Email input is not working with valid selector

Tags: html, css, email, selector

when I set the input type to email I can't use the valid selector to it in css and when I change the type to text it works perfectly

```css
.span-name{
display:block;
}

input:focus ~ .span-name,
input:valid ~ .span-name{
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<input type="email" name = "email_config" required >
<span class = "span-name">Email Configuration</span>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS transform doesn't work on inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements)

Answer (score 2):

Your translateY isn't doing anything useful because [transform doesn't work on inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14883287/856353), but it is being applied.  Here I've also applied the color purple when it is valid, and you can see that it is working as expected.  I also applied `display: inline-block` which will let the translateY do what I suspect you want it to do.  I also changed the sibling selector to the next sibling selector so that I could re-use that style for both the email and text configurations.

```css
input:focus+.span-name,
input:valid+.span-name {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  color: purple;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" name="email_config" required>
<span class="span-name">Email Configuration</span>
<br>
<input type="text" name="email_config" required>
<span class="span-name">Text Configuration</span>
```

Comment: why it won't apply try to change the display of the span-name to block and see i add it into my question but they changed it

Comment: try using the snippet now i modified the question

Comment: I did.  It works as expected.  What are you expecting it to do that it is not?

Comment: yeah i know it works but i want when someone type in the input the value stay -100% but it is not working with email type try to change it to text and it will stay

Comment: Because *ALL* values in input type="text" are valid, while only *some* values inside input type="email" are valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209115/discussion-between-s-alhaider-and-robert-mckee).