# Why does the img tag accept the margin-top property?

Tags: css, image, margin

I am wondering why `img` tag accept margin top property?
isn't this an inline tag? and inline tags does't accept top and bottom margins?

Comment: There's no need for any code!

Comment: Use display inline-block or block.

Comment: @ashishsingh there is no need code or snippet. The question as stated is pretty clear

Comment: It isn't clear to me as a native English speaker. It sounds like OP is asking why an img tag would randomly have a top margin. A code snippet would definitely have helped to clarify.

Comment: @Turnip it's asking why we can apply margin to image when it's supposed to be an inline tag and inline tag are known to not accept margin

Comment: Yes, your edit makes it clear. But as originally written, the meaning was completely different.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english guys, I'm not a native English speaker. @Temani Afif got the point.

Comment: That is why it is important to include code. It removes ambiguity.

Comment: thanks @Turnip , now the question is altogether different

Comment: @TemaniAfif it was clear but it meant something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because img is an inline **replaced** element and it does accept `margin-top`. It behaves differently than inline **non-replaced** element (like `span` for example).

Related part of the specification detailing this: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height

Note that there is no restriction or special behavior related to margin unlike with non-replaced inline element where you can read:

> The vertical padding, border and margin of an inline, non-replaced box start at the top and bottom of the content area, and has nothing to do with the 'line-height'. But only the 'line-height' is used when calculating the height of the line box.

Same logic for width/height. They work with `img` but not with `span`.

Another related question dealing with `transform` where the same logic apply: [CSS transform doesn't work on inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14883250/8620333)