# Transition not working on hover but other changes do

Tags: html, css

I'm working on updating button styles for my company's site. I've applied my CSS changes but the transition that has worked on other sites will not work on this site. When inspecting using Dev Tools in both Edge and Chrome I can see my CSS stylings are being applied. If I add an additional property to hover, say `color: black;`, hovering over the button shows the text color change properly but the scale still does not happen.

```css
.btn {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Gotham, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-height: 35px;
  padding: 8px 15px 5px 15px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.btn-default {
  border-color: #006c9d;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #006c9d;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<p align="center">
      <a class=" btn btn-default " title="Internet Services " href="redacted ">CONNECT</a>
    </p>
```

I have tried applying other classes with the scale transition working properly to no avail. I have also tried changing the CSS to:

```
.btn {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Gotham, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    justify-content: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    min-height: 35px;
    padding: 8px 15px 5px 15px;
    line-height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    scale: 1;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.btn-default {
    border-color: #006c9d;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #006c9d;
    transition: all .2s;
}

    .btn-default:hover {
        scale: 1.05;
    }
```

Nothing different happens with these changes either. I can also add the property color: black; to the hover in Dev Tools and the text color changes but the scale does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the display of your button to something other than its inline default, like `inline-block`.

```css
.btn {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Gotham, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-height: 35px;
  padding: 8px 15px 5px 15px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform .2s;
  display:inline-block;
}

.btn-default {
  border-color: #006c9d;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #006c9d;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<p align="center">
      <a class=" btn btn-default " title="Internet Services " href="redacted ">CONNECT</a>
    </p>
```

See also [CSS transform doesn't work on inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements)

Comment: Thank you. Still learning CSS and was not aware that transitions don't work on inline elements. Added the display: inline-block and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Your **< p >** element has a typo, missing ". When you solve this one, try to add this property to the a element:

display:inline-block;