# How to set the width of a label in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following HTML code to create a form but the width of the "phone" label seems to be ignored no matter what I set it to. I've set it explicitly to 50px.

[image]

```
<div name="VGroup968" style="position:absolute;left:36px;top:54px;width:380px;height:166px;">
    <div style="padding-bottom:6px"><div name="HGroup568" style="width:180px;height:23px;">
        <div style="display:inline;padding-right:2px"><label name="Label589" style="position:relative;vertical-align: middle;width:50px;height:12px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;">Phone</label></div>
        <div style="display:inline;"><input type="input" name="TextInput547" style="width:120px;height:22px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;padding:0;border:1px solid #696969;"/></div>
    </div></div>
    <div style="padding-bottom:6px"><div name="HGroup616" style="width:180px;height:23px;">
        <div style="display:inline;padding-right:2px"><label name="Label665" style="position:relative;vertical-align: middle;width:50px;height:12px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;">Message</label></div>
        <div style="display:inline;"><input type="input" name="TextInput554" style="width:120px;height:22px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;padding:0;border:1px solid #696969;"/></div>
    </div></div>
```

Is there something I'm missing? 
http://jsfiddle.net/EsdQB/1/

Comment: Did you try max-width

Comment: are ya using a CSS library(ie. Bootstrap)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The width property does not apply to non-replaced inline elements (such as `label`).

Add `display: inline-block` and it will work.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EsdQB/6/)

From the [w3c spec on the width property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-width):

> Applies to:   all elements but non-replaced inline elements, table
>   rows, and row groups

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12468620/703717) which roughly sums up that *non-replaced* inline elements - means:

inline elements that can contain text like `<a>, <span> <label>` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use inline-block

```
display: inline-block;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EsdQB/5/

Also, instead of inline styling, use [Style Sheets](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).