# Why <img> takes a height when it's an inline element?

Tags: html, css

My browser shows that the `<img>` tag is an inline tag. Numerous answers in Stack says that span does not accept an height property **because** it's an inline tag.
How can `<img>` do that ? Why isn't it rather an inline-block element ?

Comment: That's an excellent question!  I've never thought about that before...

Comment: img is technically an inline-*replaced* element. So it can take a width and a height: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/img-elements-block-level-element-or-inline-element

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468176/what-is-a-non-replaced-inline-element.

Comment: The `img` tag is a replaced element, see here for what that is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element

Comment: This question is based on a false premise; that `<img>` is an inline element. As already asked and answered here [“img” elements: Block level element or inline element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402761/img-elements-block-level-element-or-inline-element), it is not.

Comment: The answer of this question (mentioned as duplicate) isn't correct: <img> are not strictly inline-block element. And he's right, <img> is an inline (replaced) tag. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#edef-IMG

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`<img>` tag is not strictly an *inline element*, but a ***inline-replaced element***.

In a nutshell, it means that `<img>` (and other elements, as `<video>` or, `<object>` if you still use it), has **intrinsic dimensions**. So CSS can handle those dimensions (and other properties, such as margins). Because **`<img>` is an inline tag, that is *replaced* by its own source file** (well, it's still an inline element).

Some doc about that :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element
- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#edef-IMG

*Funny fact (I guess) : you can't override (or simply handle) inline-replaced behavior to "normal" inline behavior on those elements with CSS (when it works when you set it to inline-block or block or whatever you want). See this example : http://jsfiddle.net/s8apbbof/*