# Can not padding DIV element

Tags: html, css

I have listed HTML and CSS code below.

```css
.a{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.b {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.c li{
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="b">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="c">
    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But I can't control padding / margin `<div class="c">`. Why and how do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: If you do not wish to use display:inline-block, you will have to add the padding to the ul rather than the li.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding does not behave as you expect on *inline* elements.

As [Alohci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42585/alohci) pointed out in comment below, padding doesn't affect line-height for [non-replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12468176/2170192) inline elements, thus not affecting height of parent element.

**You can use `display: inline-block`** instead (see below).

Note that **`inline-block` is [not supported in IE <= 7](http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block)**. 
If you care about archaic browsers, you may use `float`s instead.

```css
.a{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.b {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.c li{
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
</div>
<div class="b">
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
</div>
<div class="c">
 <ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "applicable" is not the correct term. Padding *is* applicable to inline (both replaced and non-replaced) elements, and you can see this by giving the element a non-transparent background. But for non-replaced inline elements, the padding does not affect the line height of the element and hence does not affect the height of the containing block element, which is why the position of the li elements isn't affected by the top padding.

Answer (score 1):

Your `li` elements are `inline`, changing to `inline-block` will solve this issue. See this SO question/answer to understand the difference between inline and inline-block: [What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

```css
.a{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.b {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.c li{
 display: inline-block;
 padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
</div>
<div class="b">
 <br>
 <br>
 <br>
</div>
<div class="c">
 <ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```