# Input text height is broken in safari

Tags: html, css

I am looking to create a text input where the text fills up the whole input field vertically. As illustrated in the image below:

[image]

This works all fine in Firefox and Chrome.

In Safari I am seeing this problem:

[image]

It seems like the line-height is not applied properly for the input field. Funny enough it is applied correctly for the placeholder.

My code:

Html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="ABCD" value="ABCD">
```

Css:

```
input {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  height: 140px;
  line-height: 140px;
  width: 600px;
  font-size: 185px;
}
```

You can test my code with this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/0xsven/16z9Lr6t/

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Edit: I am on Mac OS with Safari 10.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
<div class="text-box">
<input type="text" placeholder="ABCD" value="">
</div>
<div class="text-box">
<input type="text" placeholder="ABCD" value="ABCD">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.text-box input {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 185px;
  position: relative;
  top: -47px;
}

.text-box {
  background:#fff;
  height: 140px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Live jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/16z9Lr6t/3/

Comment: That works. Thank you. Would you say this is a bug in Safari?

Comment: @Sven Safari does not understand 'line-height'. I think it is a feature of this browser

Answer (score 0):

Do not use line-height property in any line-level tags; apply only to block-level tags.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Comment: > On non-replaced inline elements, line-height specifies the height that is used to calculate line box height.

Comment: @kuba: Thanks for answering. Removing the line-height the problem persists. (Will update the title.) Any chance you can give me a tip that solves the problem?

Comment: @Justinas what does "non-replaced" even mean? Edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468176/what-is-a-non-replaced-inline-element
But how does it help me?

Answer (score 0):

`line-height` specifies only boundaries of text, not actual text placement in that box.

Try setting [`vertical-align: middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) (or some other value, can't test right now).