# inline img tag with width value

Tags: html, css, image, inline

All the inline element doesn't respect width value, they will take only required amount of width.
Why this is not the case with img tag? After setting the display to inline image is respecting width value specified in html.
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FYECKCZDC3GO

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="smiley.gif" style="display:inline;" alt="Smiley face" width="420" height="42">   
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is if you have span tag which is inline by default, now you if you add width to it, It will not have any rendering diff because span is inline. Why the same is not true for images?

Comment: Didn't get you brother. Can u be more specific? I am seeing that the image is taking space as defined in inline style.

Thanks

Comment: `img` is a `replaced inline element`. here is an answer that you might find helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471525/9870559

Comment: @NayeemParvezChowdhury My question is if you have span tag which is inline now you if you add width it will not have any rendering diff because span is inline. Why the same is not true for images?

Answer (score 0):

If the element represents an image, the user agent is expected to treat the element as a replaced element and render the image according to the rules for doing so defined in CSS.

**Height property apply to replaced inline elements.**

More can be read here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12468246/7634550

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#outer-role